# For a transmitting Antenna, can the gain be positive in decibel scale?

Tags: antenna, gain

Gain in dB scale of the transmitting antenna is:

$$G=10\cdot\log \frac{P_o}{P_i}$$

The input power will always be larger than the output power. However, I see a lot of radiation pattern graphs with positive gains in dB. How is that possible? Shouldn't the gain value ALWAYS be negative as the power ratio P_o\P_i will always be less than zero?

Comment: The gain is always the ratio to a perfect omnidirectional antenna in that direction.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you read the [Wikipedia article about Antenna gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_gain)

Antenna gain is defined as the power radiated in a certain direction (so for a directional antenna, you would obviously choose the direction to which most power is radiated) **relative** to the power if the antenna was omnidirectional. Meaning: it radiates an equal amount of power in all directions.

So a high gain antenna will "focus" all power in one (or more) directions and that is defined as "gain".